# How to find the matched string with a specific pattern

Tags: c#, string

I need to find out all the strings match the specific pattern from a big string buffer.

For example, I have a string like

```
"2014:11:12 13:30:05 Tested for ABCD at 12:30 2014:11:12 13:31:05 Tested for ABBB at 12:31 2014:11:12 13:32:05 Tested for ABCC at 12:32"
```

And I want to have an output like this:

```
2014:11:12 13:30:05 ABCD 12:30
2014:11:12 13:31:05 ABBB 12:31
2014:11:12 13:32:05 ABCC 12:32
```

I have tried with similar code like:

```
string data = "2014:11:12 13:30:05 Tested for ABCD at 12:30 2014:11:12 13:31:05 Tested for ABBB at 12:31 2014:11:12 13:32:05 Tested for ABCC at 12:32";
MatchCollection matches =  Regex.Matches("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} Tested for [?]{4} at [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}");

/* But matches.count is always 0 here, looks like the pattern [?]{4} not work */

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string temp = match.Value;
    Match dateTime = Regex.Match(temp, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}");

    Match Org = Regex.Match(temp, "Tested for [?]{4}").Value, "[?]{4}");

    Match processingTime = Regex.Match(temp, "at [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}").Value, "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}");

    /* then parse the field datetime, Org and processingTime and write to console */
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and tell us what hasn't worked? Maybe then we can help you figure out what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using Regex. I'm no expert at it, and I'm sure a better regex expression exists for the job, but this should do the trick(omitting error catching).

```
string input = "2014:11:12 13:30:05 Tested for ABCD at 12:30 2014:11:12 13:31:05 Tested for ABBB at 12:31 2014:11:12 13:32:05 Tested for ABCC at 12:32";
string regex = @"(\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) Tested for (.*?) at (\d{2}:\d{2})";
Regex r = new Regex(regex);

var matchCollection = r.Matches(input);
var outputStrings = matchCollection.Cast<Match>().Select(m => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3])).ToList();
outputStrings.ForEach(str => Console.WriteLine());
```